# How to compile an old version of gcc, say 2.95.2?

Tags: linux, gcc

My ubuntu installed with gcc 4.3.2. But I need gcc 2.95.2 to compile some of my code. I have downloaded the source of 2.95.2. But when I tried to compile it with 4.3.2, i failed. How could I get the 2.95.2 compiled?

Many thanks...

### Update

Please take a look at this thread: [How to build old source code with latest GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693632/how-to-build-old-source-code-with-latest-gcc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd try and install the following packages:

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/i386/cpp-2.95/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/i386/gcc-2.95/download
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/i386/g++-2.95/download

I'm not sure if they would work or not, but I suspect that they will.

Comment: These links now lead to error pages, but the packages might still be reachable from the [Debian snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/) webpage, such as [this snapshot](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070204T000000Z/pool/main/g/gcc-2.95/), but there is no guarantee it will work at all with newer code.